# Method to display monthly compounding values?

Tags: c#, .net, list, visual-studio, data-structures

I'm new to Object Orientated Programming and I need to come up with a way to display values for each month which are compounded by a specific interest rate. I was originally thinking of a list and having each value in the list compounded by the previous value but I have no idea how to actually implement this.

The user at the moment can specify their initial investment and get their final value at the end of the period using the following formula:

```
double initialInvestmentReturn = Math.Pow(1 + ((InterestRate / 100) / 12), 12 * numberOfYears + (numberOfMonths)) * initialInvestment;
```

The user should then be able to specify a constant monthly investment to be compounded monthly and tallied up at the end. To find the monthly return on just one month, this is the formula I have used:

```
double monthlyInterestReturn = Math.Pow(1 + ((InterestRate / 100) / 12), 1) * monthlyInvestment;
```

And this is the method I'm attempting to use currently:

```
ArrayList monthlyValues = new ArrayList();
            int counter = 0;

            while (0 == 0)
            {
                monthlyValues.Add(monthlyInterestReturn);

                if (monthlyValues.Count == numberOfMonths + (numberOfYears * 12))
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

            foreach (double d in monthlyValues)
            {
                counter++;
                double var = monthlyInvestment * counter;
                double result = Math.Pow(1 + ((InterestRate / 100) / 12), counter) * var;

                rtfTestBox.Text += result.ToString("#.##") + Environment.NewLine;

            }
```

Since the only applicable data structure I've been taught fully is Array/ArrayList (which I'm told is obsolete by SO users) I've tried to find a way to set the next value in the AL to the compounded value of the previous index value but to no avail. The output I'm getting is below which as you can see isn't quite correct.

```
//100 invested per month for 3 years 0 months at 12% annual interest:
    101
    204.02
    309.09
    416.24
    525.51
    636.91
    750.49
    866.29
    984.32
    1104.62
    1227.24
    1352.19
    1479.52
    1609.26
    1741.45
    1876.13
    2013.32
    2153.07
    2295.41
    2440.38
    2588.02
    2738.37
    2891.47
    3047.36
    3206.08
    3367.67
    3532.16
    3699.61
    3870.06
    4043.55
    4220.11
    4399.81
    4582.68
    4768.76
    4958.11
    5150.77
```

The project is a .NET C# application in visual studio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'd be more than happy to provide more detail if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentions, ArrayList is obsolete. The goto datastructure in c# is [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1). When we talk about money the recommended type is [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) this avoids some rounding issues with the other floating point types.

For this case we can use something called [iterator block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) for even more convenience:

```
    public static IEnumerable<decimal> CompoundIntrest(decimal initialAmount, decimal yearlyIntrestRatePercent, decimal monthlyInvestmentRate)
    {
        var montlyIntrest = 1 + yearlyIntrestRatePercent / (1200);
        var currentAmount = initialAmount;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return currentAmount;
            currentAmount = currentAmount * montlyIntrest + monthlyInvestmentRate;                
        }
    }
```

Called like

```
        var amounts = CompoundIntrest(100, 12, 100).Take(36);
        foreach(var a in amounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("N1"));
        }
```

Note the `Take(36)`, this determines how many months to take values from, preventing an infinite loop. There is also use the [ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.1) method to convert it to an actual list.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just to add onto what you've said, although the ToList method can also print the list, since I'm creating a .net application I have used the following code: rtfTestBox.Text += "£" + "\t" + (v.ToString("N1")) + Environment.NewLine;  Which automatically prints out each months value for each month.